# Falta una condición de exclusión a mi consulta SQL de Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta en SQL Server

```
SELECT (
    CASE TIPO_MOVIMIENTO 
                 WHEN 9 THEN null
                 WHEN 1 THEN 'Alta'
                 WHEN 8 THEN 'Reing'
                 WHEN 7 THEN 'M/S'
                 WHEN 2 THEN 'Baja'
                 WHEN 13 THEN 'ISM'
    END
) as TIPO_MOVIMIENTO,
FECHA_MOVIMIENTO,
SALARIO_DIARIO
 FROM SUA_MOVIMIENTOS 
WHERE CLAVE_PATRONAL='Y6043228102'
AND PERIODO = '202201'
AND AFILIACION = '07028507015'
AND TIPO_MOVIMIENTO IN (1,2,7,8,9,13)
order by FECHA_MOVIMIENTO
```

Este es el resultado de la consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo quiero lograr es que los TIPO_MOVIMIENTO ISM (13) NO aparezcan, pero solamente cuando su FECHA_MOVIMIENTO sea igual a la FECHA_MOVIMIENTO de los M/S (7).

Por tanto quisiera que la consulta en este caso devolviera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero encontrar una buena forma de hacer esto.

gracias...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día Sándor, hay diferentes formas de hacer lo que necesitas, ya sea con un full inner join, un union, etc.
Yo lo hice de la siguiente manera (OJO en este ejemplo uso una variable del tipo "table" ya que por lo que veo no es mucha información la que devuelve el query, de ser lo contrario es mejor que uses una tabla temporal para que el performance sea el ideal):

```
    declare @table as table
    (
        TipoMovimiento int,
        TipoMovimientoText nvarchar(50),
        FechaMovimiento date,
        Sal money
    )
    
    
    insert into @table
    SELECT TIPO_MOVIMIENTO,
    (
        CASE TIPO_MOVIMIENTO 
                     WHEN 9 THEN null
                     WHEN 1 THEN 'Alta'
                     WHEN 8 THEN 'Reing'
                     WHEN 7 THEN 'M/S'
                     WHEN 2 THEN 'Baja'
        END
    ) as TIPO_MOVIMIENTO,
    FECHA_MOVIMIENTO,
    SALARIO_DIARIO
     FROM SUA_MOVIMIENTOS 
    WHERE CLAVE_PATRONAL='Y6043228102'
    AND PERIODO = '202201'
    AND AFILIACION = '07028507015'
    AND TIPO_MOVIMIENTO IN (1,2,7,8,9)
    --order by FECHA_MOVIMIENTO
    
    
    insert into @table
    SELECT TIPO_MOVIMIENTO,
     'ISM' as TIPO_MOVIMIENTO,
    FECHA_MOVIMIENTO,
    SALARIO_DIARIO
    from SUA_MOVIMIENTOS a
    left join @table s on s.TipoMovimiento=7 and s.FechaMovimiento=a.FECHA_MOVIMIENTO
    where a.TIPO_MOVIMIENTO=13
    and CLAVE_PATRONAL='Y6043228102'
    AND PERIODO = '202201'
    AND AFILIACION = '07028507015'
    and s.FechaMovimiento is null
    
    select * 
    from @table
    order by FechaMovimiento
```

Answer (score 2):

Mi recomendación es siempre utilizar los nombres de las columnas en cualquier comando insert. El proceso para hacerlo en una tabla temporal para un mejor rendimiento:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') 
    IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    TipoMovimiento int,
    TipoMovimientoText nvarchar(50),
    FechaMovimiento date,
    Sal money
)
END

INSERT INTO #temp
(TipoMovimiento,  
 TipoMovimientoText,
 FechaMovimiento,
 Salary)
 SELECT TIPO_MOVIMIENTO AS 
 TipoMovimiento,
(
    CASE TIPO_MOVIMIENTO 
                 WHEN 9 THEN null
                 WHEN 1 THEN 'Alta'
                 WHEN 8 THEN 'Reing'
                 WHEN 7 THEN 'M/S'
                 WHEN 2 THEN 'Baja'
    END
) AS TipoMovimientoText,
FECHA_MOVIMIENTO AS FechaMovimiento,
SALARIO_DIARIO AS Salary
 FROM SUA_MOVIMIENTOS 
WHERE CLAVE_PATRONAL='Y6043228102'
AND PERIODO = '202201'
AND AFILIACION = '07028507015'
AND TIPO_MOVIMIENTO IN (1,2,7,8,9) 

DELETE s
FROM SUA_MOVIMIENTOS a
LEFT JOIN #Temp s on s.TipoMovimiento=7 and s.FechaMovimiento=a.FECHA_MOVIMIENTO
WHERE a.TIPO_MOVIMIENTO=13
AND CLAVE_PATRONAL='Y6043228102'
AND PERIODO = '202201'
AND AFILIACION = '07028507015'
AND s.FechaMovimiento is not null

SELECT a.TipoMovimiento,
 a.TipoMovimientoText,
 a.FechaMovimiento,
 a.Salary
FROM #table As a
ORDER BY a.FechaMovimiento

DROP TABLE #Temp
GO
```